# Density of normal matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, functional-analysis

A matrix $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is said to be normal if $A^*A=AA^*$, where $A^*$ is the Hermitian conjugate. Consider $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ with its norm topology.

**Question:** Is the space of normal matrices dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$?

*Thoughts:* I know that the space of all diagonalisable matrices is dense in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$, and that a matrix is normal if and only if it is unitarily diagonalizable. So the question amounts to asking whether the unitarily diagonalizable matrices still form a dense subset.

Comment: Since $A \mapsto A^\ast A - A A^\ast$ is continuous, the set of normal matrices is closed. So it cannot be dense for $n > 1$.

Comment: If it was dense then every matrix would be normal, as the conjugation is continuous.

Comment: @geometricK You might find [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/933138/81360) interesting.

Comment: Another way of specifying normality is via Schur's Inequality $\big\Vert A\big\Vert_F^2 \geq \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k\vert^2$ with equality *iff* $A$ is normal.  So let e.g. $A$ be a non-zero nilpotent matrix.  It is not normal so $f(A)=\big\Vert A\big\Vert_F^2 - \sum_{k=1}^n \vert \lambda_k\vert^2 = d \gt 0$.  Eigenvalues vary continuously with coordinates of a matrix so e.g. select $\epsilon :=\frac{d}{2}$ and there is a $\delta\gt 0$ ball around $A$ such that every matrix in it is not normal.

Comment: @ronno Ok, I will set it out as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mappings $(A,B) \mapsto AB$ and $A \mapsto A^\ast$ are continuous. Hence
$\Phi:M_n(\mathbb{C}) \to M_n(\mathbb{C})$, $\Phi(A)= A^\ast A-AA^\ast$ is continuous. The set of normal matrices in $M_n(\mathbb{C})$ is $\Phi^{-1}(\{0_{n\times n}\})$, and is therefore closed. If $n > 1$, for example each nontrivial nilpotent matrix is not normal and is therefore an inner point of $M_n(\mathbb{C}) \setminus \Phi^{-1}(\{0_{n\times n}\})$. Thus  $\Phi^{-1}(\{0_{n\times n}\})$ is not dense.