# What is the dimension of the (sub)-space of normal endomorphisms?

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds, submanifold

The question is in the title. To make it more precise, I am asking for the dimension of the set of (non-singular) normal endomorphisms of ${\bf K}^n$, seen as a submanifod $V_n$ of $GL(K^n)$, where $K={\bf R}$ or ${\bf C}$. (An endomorphism $A\in End(K^n)$ is normal if $AA^*=A^*A$, where $A^*$ denotes the adjoint of $A$ in the complex case, or its transpose in the real case.)

My guess is that the answer must be $n(n+1)/2$, but is there a simple proof, and could it be that the subspace in question is singular? Indeed, for $K={\bf C}$, $V_n$ is the image of the map $\phi:{\rm Diag}_n(K^*)\times O(K^n)$ defined by $\phi(D,U)=U^*DU$ (where I hope the notations are clear). This map is clearly differentiable but is also singular at $(D,U)=(I_n,I_n)$, where $I_n$ denotes the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Comment: Please state explicitly what you mean by "normal". I suspect that you mean $A$ is normal if $A^TA = AA^T$ in the real case and $A^*A = AA^*$ in the complex case

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/933283/81360). For thew case of $K = \Bbb C$, $V_n$ is a **real** manifold within $GL(\Bbb C^n)$ that has dimension $n(n+1)$

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Yes, exactly, by saying that an endomorphism $A$ is "normal" I mean that it commutes with its adjoint $A^*$ (resp. its transpose $A^T$) in the complex case (resp. the real case). Also, by $O(K^n)$ above I mean the orthogonal group in the real case, and the unitary group in the complex case.